# dnSpy showing strange disassembly code for async methods

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, disassembly, dnspy

I am trying to disassemble my .NET core 3.1 binary using the latest build of dnSpy but am getting output like this:

[image]

The original method:

```
public async Task<List<FirmwarePackage>> CalculatePackagesDeltaAsync(List<FirmwarePackage> firmwarePackages) {
  var packagesToUpdate = await GetPackageDifferences(firmwarePackages);

  // sort packages
  // "version-update" packages should be updated last, with "mez" being last
  packagesToUpdate = packagesToUpdate
    .OrderBy(x => x.TargetType)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Name)
    .ToList();

  packagesToUpdate.RemoveAll(x => x.Name == "version-update");

  var versionPkgs = firmwarePackages
    .Where(x => x.Name == "version-update")
    .OrderBy(x => x.TargetType);

  packagesToUpdate.AddRange(versionPkgs);
  return packagesToUpdate;
}
```

Is this normal? How can I make it into something more understandable. Trying to debug this is a nightmare.

On the github repo the `issues` is not available which is why I am asking here.

Answer (score 9):

For those of you watching at home, echoing @yoelhalb from their comment

> Actually it is a setting in Options->Decompiler->C#->Show hidden decompiler generated classes and methods

Answer (score 4):

What you can see there is totally normal. What you have cropped is just one part of the generated code.

The highlighted code saves the local variables (as fields of the state machine) to preserve their state.

The code generation is quite complex because there are couple of use cases that are handled in the different way. But the generic ideas are written quite well in the following articles:

- [Sergey Tepliakov's blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/)
- [Dixon's blog](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-c-sharp-async-await-1-compilation)
- [Ranjeet Signh's blog](https://ranjeet.dev/understanding-how-async-state-machine-works/)
- etc.

[Stephen Toub has written a blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-valuetask-pooling-in-net-5/) which reveals some of the optimizations that the .NET team has accomplished in .NET 5.

Comment: Why do other disassemblers like `dotPeek` show the above code properly?

Comment: @ColtonScottie https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63783101/how-i-can-see-the-async-state-machine-async-await-under-the-hood-with-the-help

Comment: Yeh the problem with dnSpy however is that it doesn't show the actual state machine code either... it only shows the rewritten function and not the actual state machine object used by the function.

Comment: Actually it is a setting in `Options->Decompiler->C#->Show hidden decompiler generated classes and methods`

Comment: yoel halb thank you! Changing that setting finally allowed me to debug my issue.

Comment: @yoelhalb great! Now the hidden function revealed.

Answer (score 2):

**dnSpyEx**

There is a new library based on dnSpy called dnSpyEx that does it correctly, find it on [GitHub here](https://github.com/dnSpyEx/dnSpy).

This library will decompile the code back in human readable `async`/`await` code (provided the `View->Options->Decompiler->C#->Decompile async methods (async/await)` is checked).

If you do want to see the compiler generated state machines you can either uncheck the above setting, or check the `View->Options->Decompiler->C#->Show hidden decompiler generated classes and methods` setting.

**dnSpy**

For the old dnSpy (which is archived as of now) there is no way to see it as normal code, instead you should check the `View->Options->Decompiler->C#->Show hidden decompiler generated classes and methods` otherwise the code will be missing at all.